# Ansible "warm up" deployment

Tags: deployment, ansible

I have the playbook below (simplified).

It works great, but I'd like to be able to do a warmup where I only deploy to a single host (like serial: 1) and then pause so I can check logs to verify everything is fine before releasing to something as large as 33% of all my services.

Is there an easy way Ansible lets you do this?

I have a really hacky solution in place right now involving essentially copy and pasting my code with serial: 1, a fail statement, a pile of when checks and command line arguments. There has to be a better way than ruining an otherwise clean and readable playbook. I'm just not sure what it might be.

```
- name: 33% at a time max-analytics deploy
  hosts: role_max_logger
  serial: 33%
  tasks:
    - name: take out of lb analytics
      shell: haproxy stuff
    - pause:
        seconds: 5
    - name: gracefulReloading max-analytics
      shell: reload stuff
    - name: add back to lb analytics
      shell: haproxy stuff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of Ansible 2.2 you can set dynamic [batch size](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_delegation.html#rolling-update-batch-size).

```
---
- hosts: mygroup
  serial:
   - 1
   - 33%
  tasks:
    - shell: date
    - pause:
        prompt: check if everything ok
      when: ansible_play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) == 0
```

This will take only one host in the first batch, execute date command on that host and pause if the current host is the first in play hosts. So it'll pause only once and then 33% batches will go without pausing.

Answer (score 0):

You can make the serial as variable, and pass in the amount that you want the playbook to run. For example, you can pass in "1" as the serial, and towards the end of the playbook, if the variable is "1", exit the playbook.

If the variable is not "1", the playbook will continue with other servers. Your first server might be deployed again, but no issue, as your changes should be already up to date.

More information from here: http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/playbooks_variables.html#passing-variables-on-the-command-line

and use fail module to exit if the variable is "1" : http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/fail_module.html